# did I not provide a possible answer?

Tags: discussion

While admittedly so basic I nearly didn't post it, isn't this a legitmate answer to the asker's question?

[Oracle UPDATE followed by SELECT in LinqPad](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42203/oracle-update-single-record-with-multiple-where-conditions/42452?noredirect=1#comment74637_42452)

Just want to make sure I'm following the community rules...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Brevity is NOT an implicit problem; it's simply an indicator that is often associated with incomplete answers.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/841/what-to-do-about-one-liner-answers#comment2875_842)

However, after you posted your answer, the OP commented on the question with:

> I did try terminating my statement with a ; but that didn't work

My take on this is that since that comment from the OP, your answer is now 'not an answer', because the aim is to provide a solution to the OP's *actual problem*.

For that reason, I'd say the best course of action is now to convert the answer to a comment. If the missing semi-colon was the issue, then I'd have upvoted your answer, and of course closed the question as 'too localized'!

Comment: Makes sense - I didn't see that comment, so I get it now.  :)  Thanks, Jack!